# jQuery, passing success data from AJAX to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I'm trying to get the success data from a jquery Ajax call so I can use it elsewhere but for some reason its only accessible within the actual success call, so immeditaly below works but the other doesnt'.. any advice is appreciated

```
      success: function(data) {
        alert (data)
      }
```

this doesn't work when I try to pass "data" onto another function

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/site1/utilities/ajax_component_call_handler',
      data: {
            component_function: component_function,
            param_array: param_array
            },
            dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        receiver (data)
      }
    });

}
```

my ajax success is calling this:

```
function receiver (data) {

    ajax_return = data
alert (ajax_return)
}
```

Comment: does your receiver function get called?  Have you checked in firebug?  Also, are you doing this inbetween script tags or in a plugin/object?

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure `receiver()` is in the proper scope? For example, if the `$.ajax()` call is outside `$(document).ready(function() {...})`, but the `receiver()` is inside, then `receiver()` will not be visible from where you're calling it.

Comment: the issue was the var name "data", it was calling the function but not passing the data variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `data` as a variable name. jQuery objects have an object called `data` already which holds arbitrary data. If you call your variable `dat`, you should get better results.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

A shorter implementation could be to just say `success: receiver` with no parameters, and write your receiver signature as

```
function receiver(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Then data is passed by the jQuery callback.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `data` as a variable name. I can't see any conflict with jQuery's `data` method.

Comment: thanks, that was it.. odd how jquery uses "data" in their examples, at least thats where I think I got the var name from

Comment: @Rick - Was there some other relevant code you didn't post? All the examples of `data` in your code above are within closures. There shouldn't be any sort of conflict.

Comment: In that context, there's a conflict. Because his example assigns `data` an object, then refers to `success: function(data) { receiver(data) };`.

A shorter implementation could be to just say `success: receiver` with no parameters, and write your receiver signature as `function receiver(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { /* ... */ }`. Then `data` is passed by the jQuery callback.

Comment: sidewaysmilk - Still doesn't make sense to me. The `data:` in the `xhr` request would be accessible via `this.data`. If there's a conflict, it would seem that doing `alert(data)` as OP did in the first example would result in the same conflict. Even if the `data:` from the `xhr` request was being overwritten, it wouldn't seem to prevent the function from being called. I'm having no issue in identical tests. Oh well.

Comment: @patrick dw - I see what you mean. Hrm. The thing that I think looks funny is the `receiver(data)`. I think that this might be interpreted as `receiver({component_function: component_function, param_array: param_array})`, but I'm definitely not sure. :) Because it seems fuzzy, I wouldn't reuse "data."

Comment: sidewaysmilk - Well, changing the name did solve the issue for OP. I'd just be curious as to why. I've a feeling that we're missing some code. Even if `receiver()` was called in the manner you suggested in the comment above, the `alert()` would still work. It would just give `[object Object]`. I guess we'll never know for sure what happened. :o)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/site1/utilities/ajax_component_call_handler',
    data: {
        component_function: component_function,
        param_array: param_array
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: receiver
});
```

Or simply use another variable name other than `data` as it is already used.